# Master-Master merge replication with MongoDB using mongooplog

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering if it's possible building a master to master merge replication with MongoDB using the mongooplog command.

For example:

```
# mongooplog --from master2 --host master1
# mongooplog --from master1 --host master2
```

The problem with this solution is that mongooplog ends when it reaches the last oplog, and it doesn't save the last backed oplog, and it should repeat last n operations.

Is this solution a good approach to solve net splits?
How does mongooplog deal with distributed timestamps?

I think it would be a good approach if a primary could accept inserting oplogs from another replica set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this solution a good approach to solve net splits? How does mongooplog deal with distributed timestamps?

No, what you're proposing with `mongooplog` is not possible and will lead to data loss. The MongoDB replication & tool internals assume a common [oplog history and idempotent order of operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/), and your suggested approach will violate those assumptions.

Multi-master support requires some sort of conflict/merge resolution. MongoDB replication (as at 2.6) is designed to only support a single master (aka "primary").

Replica sets are MongoDB's supported method for [automatic failover](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/#automatic-failover), so in the event of a net split or server failure you need to plan an appropriate deployment to ensure a primary can be elected.

> I think it would be a good approach if a primary could accept inserting oplogs from another replica set.

There is an open request you can upvote/watch in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-2956: Master-Master replication](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2956). This is a feature being considered on the longer term roadmap, but is not currently scheduled for a release.

#### Possible approaches

While not full substitutes for multi-master, there are a few approaches you could consider depending on your deployment requirements:

- Deploy a sharded cluster using [tag-aware sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/tag-aware-sharding/) to isolate data to certain shards. In a deployment with multiple data centres you can effectively end up with local writes (for data stored on local shards) and local reads (if you're okay with reading from a secondary with eventual consistency).
- Implement your own API which handles conflict resolution and some multi-master features. An example I've seen (but never tried) is [MongoMVCC](https://github.com/igd-geo/mongomvcc/wiki).